# How to schedule a task with interval dinamically getted from a SQL query in application runtime?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, scheduled-tasks

I must do a scheduler where the interval is getted from a SQL query in application runtime. If the value is updated on DB, my service must apply it on scheduled task.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    private long interval = 1000;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar;

    @Autowired
    public SchedulingConfiguration(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        this.taskRegistrar = taskRegistrar;
        taskRegistrar.addFixedRateTask(this::myTask, interval);
    }

    private void myTask() {
        logger.info("Running at {}", LocalTime.now());
    }

    public void updateIntervalFromDatabase() {
        String sql = """
                SELECT plataforma.platform_interval
                FROM plataformas_dev plataforma
                WHERE platform_name = 'VTEX';""";
        Long newInterval = Objects.requireNonNull(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, Long.class));
        if (!Objects.equals(newInterval, interval)) {
            interval = newInterval;
            taskRegistrar.destroy();
            configureTasks(taskRegistrar);
        }
    }
}
```

The class SchedulingConfiguration overrides the method configureTasks to create the scheduled task with the interval obtained from the global variable interval. The method updateIntervalFromDatabase is responsible for get the value from database. This method is called from class above

```
@Configuration
public class PlatformService {
    private final SchedulingConfiguration schedulingConfigurer;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    @Autowired
    public PlatformService(SchedulingConfiguration schedulingConfigurer) {
        this.schedulingConfigurer = schedulingConfigurer;
        scheduleIntervalUpdate();
    }
        private void scheduleIntervalUpdate() {
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(schedulingConfigurer::updateIntervalFromDatabase, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

The method scheduleIntervalUpdate must run every 10 seconds to get the interval from database using the updateIntervalFromDatabase method from the other class.

My problem is that once my application getted the value from DB at startup, my scheduled task will run at this interval for whole life, don't matter how much times I update the value in DB. Any idea for fix it? I know my code is a mess. I'll fix this after this scheduling start to work.

I've tried every solution I've found. I expect the scheduler receives the value from database in application runtime and uses this as interval